# how can i find malware code and remove from wordpress site to stop it redirecting to hackers click view pages

Tags: redirect, hacked

how can I find malware code and remove from a WordPress site to stop it redirecting to hackers click view pages

Comment: https://sucuri.net/

Answer (score 0):

ALthough hacking is not a subject that is allowed here (I suspect your question will get put on hold as soon as someone else notices), there are lots of resources available on the googles/bings/ducks to help with cleaning up a site.

The process involves changing credentials everywhere (hosting, ftp, WordPress admin users); updating everything (WordPress, themes, plugins) from original files, looking for rouge files everywhere on the site, and more.

I've put together a procedure I use here: https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ .

It takes a bit of time, but has worked for me in the past as I have cleaned sites successfully with that procedure.

Good luck.

Comment: Cheers Rick. I have one other issue i don't seem able to overcome, after wasting hours looking as usual. My server is controlled through plesk cpanel but will not allow me to edit files allocated to "root" user or group even after i have changed the permissions temporarily to 755 everywhere 
I am about to try to FTP an edited css file to clear this hack (or part of it) but I guess it also will not let me upload a new css file as the directory seems to not allow me to create files or directories.

Comment: I have no problem where files and directories are allocated to other users, especially myself as owner, but this root / apache user restriction is bugging me, pardon the pun

Comment: Might be time to talk to your hosting support gang. All the sites that I contracted to repair had full FTP access to the site/domain root, so I was able to wander through all the folders looking for files that shouldn't be there (if you update everything, then sorting by date helps find those files). Good luck.